# in Eclipse, define nested class

Tags: java, class, nested

I am trying to define a nested class using Eclipse....

```
public class Xxx {

    private boolean[][] grid;
    private boolean OPEN = true;
    private Site[][] s;

    class Site() {

        private int val;

        Site() {               // empty constructor


        }
    }

    public Xxx(int N) {

........
    }
.......
}
```

On the line defining the inner class, Site, I get an error...

Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token "class", @ expected
    - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block

Is my syntax wrong? I don't understand the message.

Answer (score 10):

Remove the `()`:

```
class Site {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class `Site()` is not a method,its a class.Methods are followed by `()`,classes are simply followed by `{}`

```
public class Xxx {

    private boolean[][] grid;
    private boolean OPEN = true;
    private Site[][] s;

    class Site {

        private int val;

        Site() {               // empty constructor


        }
    }

    public Xxx(int N) {

........
    }
.......
}
```